# Search list result from Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, app-inventor

I'm trying to learn & use [MIT App Inventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/) to interact with the Maps app. I've successfully created a button to alter the `DataUri` and then launch the maps app via `StartActivity`.

What I'm interested in is only the search functionality of maps, without launching the app itself. I want to submit some sort of query, and receive a list in return. Can this be done for regular search as well as directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with App Inventor and the web component in case there is a RESTful Google Maps API interface, did you already find something in one of the Google Map APIs which can supply what you want?
I have an example with the Static Maps API 2.0 and App Inventor, but without the web component, see here http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#maps2button
You might want to add "google-maps" as tag in your question...

Comment: That's a great example! I was hoping to just get a list instead of displaying the actual map. I'd display it as a list, and I'd be able to display a count. Also I can't get my `make text` working. I think I have old Java

Comment: concerning your `make text` problem, post a new question and add a screenshot of your blocks.